# Interpolate Jade and Python dictionary

Tags: python, pug, pyjade

Given a jade template and a dictionary, how can I use the dictionary to populate the jade template?  For example,

```
>>> data = {
...   'name': "World",
...   'ages': [10, 20, 30]
... }

>>> template = """
... html
...   body
...     h1 "Hello, #{name}!"
...     each age in ages
...        h3 "Age: #{age}"
... """

>>> print interpolate(template, data)
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <h3>Age: 10</h2>
    <h3>Age: 20</h2>
    <h3>Age: 30</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been looking at `pyjade`, but I can't figure out where a function like `interpolate` is defined. How do I write `interpolate`?

Comment: I cant' find the bit of code used for interpolation in the `pyjade` source, so I haven't done anything other than look through that codebase.

Comment: https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/blob/master/pyjade/compiler.py#L216

Comment: Can you show me an example of its usage?

Answer (score 1):

`pyjade` doesn't give you the option to directly interpolate jade and python objects; rather, it allows conversion of jade to a format friendly to another template engine, such as Jinja2. This template engine can then do the interpolation for you. For example,

```
data = {
  'name': "World",
  'ages': [10, 20, 30]
}

template = """
div
  h1 "Hello, #{name}!"
  each age in ages
     h3 "Age: #{age}"
"""

def interpolate(template, data):
  import os
  from jinja2 import Environment

  env = Environment(
      loader     = FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()),
      extensions = ['pyjade.ext.jinja.PyJadeExtension']
  )

  # write template to disk (there's probably a way around this?)
  with open("templates/template.jade", "w") as f:
    f.write(template.strip())

  return (
    env
    .get_template("templates/template.jade")
    .render(data)
  )

print interpolate(template, data)
# <div>
#   <h1>"Hello, World!"</h1>
#   <h3>"Age: 10"</h3>
#   <h3>"Age: 20"</h3>
#   <h3>"Age: 30"</h3>
# </div>
```